# CSS : Images scale aspect to fill

Tags: html, css, image

I have a cover Image in an html page that is wrapped by a div.
The div size is always width:100% height:33%.
I want any arbitrary image to scale to fill without be stretched on any screen size and ratio.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.headerImageWrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.coverImageCentered{
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;   
  margin: auto;
}
```

My problem is that the image size is not the mimimum possible that satisfy these conditions.

[See the image to understand better](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mgmb8upb6jqpyn/stack.jpg)

I'm an iOS  developer, if you now how it works basically like the contentMode : scale aspect to fill

Comment: You can try using Media-Queries to change the size of the background, according to the screen size. It's pretty flexible. Something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get right your question, but you may try to experiment with `background-size: cover` (you won't need wrapper with this one).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you looking for.. you can test this solution on the device
http://jsbin.com/joxinizo/4

source code:

http://jsbin.com/joxinizo/4/edit

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bgd {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bgd-cover {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bgd-cover-img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 13%;
}
```

UPD: i updated my answer

UPD2:

Comment: @J.Guilherme works just fine for me. anyway just use html form UPD2